# Unable to get Directory listing of S3 bucket using PHP SDK, EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using PHP sdk to get list of files in folder form S3.

When I run the php form my localhost, I get the files listing. But when I run the same Php form EC2, it does not work, no error return.

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

require './vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$folderId = $_REQUEST["folderid"];

//echo $folderId;

// Create an S3 client
$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region'  => 'ap-south-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'zzzzzz',
        'secret'  => 'xxxxxxx',
      ),
]);

$folderPath = "thumb_images/{$folderId}/";
//echo "<br />".$folderPath."<br />";

$objects = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => 'bucket_name',
    "Prefix" => $folderPath //must have the trailing forward slash "/"
));

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the `EC2 instance` have enough permissions to read the S3-Bucket?

Comment: @MaiKaY, I think, Yes. Because I can use aws cli to move an dcopy file into S3. Also I find that the php page give error when using foreach loop to iterate in $objects.

Comment: If an IAM Role has been assigned to the Amazon EC2 instance, you do not need to pass the `credentials` array, since the AWS PHP SDK will automatically retrieve the credentials. To narrow-in on the potential problem, do some debugging on `$client` and `$objects` to confirm what was returned.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, var_dump($objects);GIVES  object(Generator)#61 (0) { }